# RegEx to match a string not containing a specific HTML tag

Tags: regex, wildcard

I want to use Regex to find content between two tags like this:

```
<br />@ This is the content.</li>
```

So far, I have been using:

```
<br />@(.*?)</li>
```

The content sometimes contains `<li>`tag, which is not what I want to look for. So now I would like to revise my search such as `match <br />@(.*?)</li>`that do not contain `<li> tag`.

Then I try: `<br />@([^<li>].*?)</li>`, but this still includes `<li>` in its search.

Can you please give me a little help? Thank you.
(Note, I use TextWrangler)

Comment: I am not sure of the flavor of regex you are using, but looks like, what you need is a non-greedy match `([^<]*)`. Note that, in a character class you mention characters, if you are thinking `[^<li>]` is same as "not containing <li>" it is not!, you can try a negative-look-ahead if it suits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Description

This expression will:

- find substrings which start with `<br />` and end with the next `</li>`
- validate the substring does not contain a `<li>`
- capture the text between the start an end tags defined above

`<br\s*\/>(@(?:(?!<li>).)*?)<\/li>`

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/CIledJX54O

Note the first line has the bad condition

```
<br />@ Don't <li>find me.</li>
<br />@ This is the content.</li>
<br />@ more desired content.</li>
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <br />@ This is the content.</li>
        [1] => <br />@ more desired content.</li>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => @ This is the content.
        [1] => @ more desired content.
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This really helps but it causes `out of stack space` error, which stops the regex from working.

Comment: Can you post how you're using the expression and some sample text that recreates the error?

Comment: Here is a sample of my text [1]: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15034088/Others/Temps/sample.txt. It works with single search, but fails with `Find all` and `Replace all` (out of stack space) [2): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15034088/Others/Temps/stack_error.png

Comment: I suspect this works as designed but the problem is within the TextWrangler tool. Your sample text doesn't have any `<br />@`...`</li>` strings which do not also contain a `<li>`. Online test tools like http://www.rubular.com/r/aKKLJ2X92h show that the expression works as desired. you can move the first line match to the end of the text string to validate it searches the entire text.

Comment: See updated http://www.rubular.com/r/nnRWUTsjgG. You'll have to scroll down to see where it's highlighting your matches and at the bottom of the page it shows capture group 1.  This tool does the same thing http://regexr.com?35jmt, you have to scroll down to find the blue highlights and hover over them to see the details on why that was matched.

Comment: I also guess the problem is kind of TextWrangler-specific. I'm on Mac and quite used to TextWrangler. OK, I will try with Notepad++ on Windows to see if it works. Despite it being stagnant now, I highly appreciate your help, and will accept it as the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: What tool did you use to draw that regex syntax diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Why this regex doesn't work:

```
#<a[^>]+href\s*=\s*(["\'])(.*?)\1[^>]*>((?:(?!</a).)*?)Domain#msi
```

I am trying to find all links which contain "Domain" string inside of their linked text. It will match the desired but also the parts of code which contain "`</a`".

For example, it will match:

```
<a href="/new-domains">New Domain
```

But also

```
<a href="/domains/url-email-forwarding">URL & Email Forwarding</a></ul></div><!--/.navigation--></div></div></li><li><a href="/hosting">Hosting</a><div><div><div class="navigation"><h1>Premium Domain
```

And when I will replace "Domain" to "`</a`" it will match all links correctly. But why it does not work with "Domain"?!

Total mystery..